# How to resolve Size memory using WampServe?

Tags: laravel, wamp

I'm developer with Laravel 7 and Wammp serve, but when trying install JWT with the follogin command : composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source, I get this error

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/composer/semver/src/Constraint/Constraint.php on line 153

how to resolve its?

Answer (score 0):

The `php.ini` file usually is on `"C:\wamp64\bin\php\php_ver"` where `"php_ver"` is the version of the PHP you are using (please note the latest version of wamp includes two version of PHP, make sure you edit the right `php.ini` file)

then search `memory_limit` and increase the limit like : `memory_limit = 128M`

Reference [here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,26266,26273)

Comment: I change the value memory_limit = 512M and run this commmand php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;" its show  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php on line 339

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes I restarted apache, but nothing I dont know whats happening